# I want to connect the Spring application with the external bukkit server through the REST API method

Tags: spring, bukkit, spigot

I want to control the bukkit server through the spring web application.

For example, send a command to the console, receive his response, etc

I'm trying to figure out a way, but I can't find a good one.

How shall I do it?

Even if third-party plugins are imported through the database, I want to find a way to do basic bukkit control.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide how to send the request to the server. It seems to me that in your case, the easiest is run the built-in java web server (HttpServer) to receive commands, and then process them.

If you need synchronous actions, then you can always do `callSyncMethod`

To receive command output, simply create your own implementation of `CommandSender` with overridden `sendMessage` methods

Im implement your idea in my plugin, you can see it on [github](https://github.com/Spliterash/HttpCommandExecutor)